# How to link that "logged in" in "you must be logged in to post a comment" with custom login page on WordPress?

Tags: plugins, redirect, wp-login-form

How to link that "logged in" in "you must be logged in to post a comment" for a post on WordPress to custom login page. So that when the user clicks on that "logged in" gets redirected to the custom login page not to the wp-login.php. Please help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could change the whole text by adding first parameter to your `comment_form` function. According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form), the code below might help:

```
$comments_args = array(
        // change the must log in text and link url
        'must_log_in'=> '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), YOUR_CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_URL ) . '</p>'
);

comment_form($comments_args);
```

Please change the 'YOUR_CUSTOM_LOGIN_PAGE_URL' accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your help. I am quit a newbie to wordpress. can you please tell me where shall i put that code. I mean in which file.

Comment: You could check out the `comments.php` in your theme first. You could replace the `comment_form();` with my code.

Comment: shall I change in comment-templte.php?

Comment: In my themes `comment.php`, there is only call for `comment_form();` so i did like this `<?php comment_form($comments_args);
$comments_args = array(
        // change the must log in text and link url
        'must_log_in'=> '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), 'http://mydomain.com/login' ) . '</p>'
); ?>` but its not working still redirecting to same page. Please help.

Comment: hey, I see an unnecessary ';' at the end of the 'mydomain.com/login'. Could you remove and try again?

And you take the wrong order, the variable should come first, then do the function call. Like my answer.

Comment: `$comments_args = array(
        // change the must log in text and link url
        'must_log_in'=> '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), 'http://mydomain.com/login' ) . '</p>'
); comment_form($comments_args);?>` I have done like this and now its working. Thanks a lot for your help.